# Restoring postgresql 9.4 crashed database

Tags: postgresql

Can anyone help me to restore my crashed database. Is there a way to use pg_resetxlog. I read a number of documentations telling about it but i'm always seeing the same log when i restart my postgresql service

```
2016-04-11 8:47:59 p.m. GMT [1710-1] LOG: the database system was interrupted during a restore at 2016-04-11 11:04:19 GMT
2016-04-11 8:47:59 p.m. GMT [1710-2] TIP: This probably means that the data has been corrupted and you
need to use the last backup for recovery.
2016-04-11 8:47:59 p.m. GMT [1710-3] LOG: the database system was not shut properly; restoration
automatic current
2016-04-11 8:47:59 p.m. GMT [1710-4] LOG: the re-execution starts at 4 / 32DF8E90
2016-04-11 8:47:59 p.m. GMT [1710-5] FATAL: could not access the transaction status 5598
2016-04-11 8:47:59 p.m. GMT [1710-6] DETAIL: Could not read the file "pg_multixact / members / 0000" at offset 57344: Success
2016-04-11 8:47:59 p.m. GMT [1710-7] BACKGROUND: xlog redo create mxiD 5598 offset 11603 Nmembers 2: 6486476 (keysh) 6,486,482 (keysh)
2016-04-11 8:47:59 p.m. GMT [1709-1] LOG: launch process (PID 1710) exits with exit code 1
2016-04-11 8:47:59 p.m. GMT [1709-2] LOG: start cancellation due to a failure in the launch process
```

I tried to fix my problem like this :

First one, saving my data in a external drive

> `scp -r /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main /media/myhdd/data`

Second One, as postgres user i run the `pg_resetxlog` command like this :

```
./pg_resetxlog -f /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/
```

The command result after pg_resetxlog is

> Resetting the transaction log

But when i try to restart my postgresql service i get the same error message. Am i doing the right command whith `pg_resetxlog` ? I'm new on postgres

Comment: Which exact (minor) version is this?  And where did you get the idea of the solution from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solve my problem.
I recreate `pg_multiaxt/members/0000` file by giving more offset. My first offset was 55344 and the new one is 100192.
The command is :

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=0000 bs=1 count=100192
```

After restarting my postgresql service my database is now working correctly.

Comment: How did you find the offset and count you needed to zero out this file?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, i fixed it a little differently:
I had a pg_clog/XXXX file which seemed corrupted (same error) after a crash:

```
FATAL:  could not access status of transaction 72608288
DETAIL:  Could not read from file "pg_clog/0045" at offset 57344: Success.
```

The file was 57344 bytes long instead of the regular 262144. So i appended zero's to the file to pad it to the correct size of 262144. Simple math: 262144-57344 = 204800. Then append it:

```
> dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=204800 >> 0045
```

After that i restarted postfix and it started up correctly. I immediatly dumped the database with pg_dump, deleted the orig db and recreated it and imported the dump. All is fine again.